# How to delete lines from cfg file with previous hours

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i want to create bash a bash script which automatically check and delete previous expired hours generated lines (cron tab). lines are automatically generated by system in my cfg file. I don't want to provide expiry date on my script because I want to delete only expired lines from my cfg file. Currently i have to self open the cfg file and then delete expired lines from them one by one. I want to make a script that delete it for me. but unable to find solution from anywhere. i am not much aware about bash, awk. but i will be very thankful if complete script should be written by experts. here is the example of my cfg file:

```
9234170 6287130 0 {enddate=2019-07-30 12:32:05}  
6378500 1306985 0 {enddate=2019-07-30 12:33:22}  
3608791 1579200 0 {enddate=2019-07-30 12:48:12}  
5012948 8975601 0 {enddate=2019-07-30 13:13:51}
```

here is my code which i have tried:

```
#! /bin/sh
awk '
BEGIN { 
now=systime() # now in epoch time
fn=60*60*24*14 # fortnight in seconds
}
{
dt=$1 " " $2 # create datetime
gsub(/["strftime"]/," ",dt) 
}
mktime(dt)>now-fn
file=var/etc/myfile.cfg  #location of my cfg file
```

suppose current date and time is `2019/07/30 13:13:15` then i want to expect my result in cfg file:

```
  5012948 8975601 0 {enddate=2019-07-30 13:13:51}
```

when i run the script in terminal, it stucks with no result.

Comment: Where is the closing single quote? That and possibly more of your script is missing. What do you expect the `gsub` command you show to do? Is your cfg file your input file? Is it also your output file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `awk` script taking as input `expireDate` in date format. Bypassing time/date calculations.

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN { 
    FPAT="[[:digit:]]{4}-[^}]+"; # assign enddate sting to $1
    expireDate = "2019-07-30 12:43:21";
}
$1 >= expireDate { # for lines with enddate >= expireDate
    print;         # print this line
}
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.cfg
```

If you want to provide `expireDate` as a parameter to the script

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN { 
    FPAT="[[:digit:]]{4}-[^}]+"; # assign enddate sting to $1
}
$1 >= expireDate { # for lines with enddate >= expireDate
    print;         # print this line
}
```

running:

```
  awk -v expireDate="2019-07-30 12:43:21" -f script.awk input.cfg
```

#### update

If you want to include the current time as `expireDate` use `date +%F\ %T` command as value.

```
 awk -v expireDate="$(date +%F\ %T)" -f script.awk input.cfg
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Actually lines are automatically generated by system in my cfg file. I don't want to privide expiry date on my script because I want to delete only expired lines from my cfg file. Currently i have to self open the cfg file and then delete expired lines from them one by one. I want to make a script that delete it for me. Also please share the code how to provide path to my cfg file.

Comment: now i understand your commands, considering your first example, is it possible that system consider only current date and time in "expiredate" field and show the result?

Comment: you may insert the system time into the awk command using `date +%F\%T` command. I will update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot dudi Boy. You have solved my problem and saved my time. i have tried all possible solutions like perl,sed and gawk method but all in vein. You are Rock.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do (compare to this hour? compare to 14 days ago? something else?) but here's a start (using GNU awk for time functions):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[=}]"
    now = strftime("%F %T")
    anHourAgo = strftime("%F %T",systime()-(60*60))
}
{ print $(NF-1) " vs " now " vs " anHourAgo }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2019-07-30 12:32:05 vs 2019-07-29 17:35:03 vs 2019-07-29 16:35:03
2019-07-30 12:33:22 vs 2019-07-29 17:35:03 vs 2019-07-29 16:35:03
2019-07-30 12:48:12 vs 2019-07-29 17:35:03 vs 2019-07-29 16:35:03
2019-07-30 13:13:51 vs 2019-07-29 17:35:03 vs 2019-07-29 16:35:03
```

Just a string comparison of those timestamps is all you need to add.

Comment: Actually lines are generated automatically in my file. I want to delete only expired lines because currently i have to manually open the cfg file and then erase these lines by myself.

Comment: Cool but that doesn't actually clarify anything. Edit your question to clearly state exactly what it is you're trying to do.